# Suppress mpi messages

Tags: mpi, openmpi

I have a program running with MPI (OpenMPI) that is filling the output with many instances of this:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun noticed that the job aborted, but has no info as to the process
that caused that situation.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Other than that, the program seems to be running fine.
I wonder if there is a way to suppress this kind of messages?

`-q` didn't done it.

Comment: This message means that one or more processes probably crashed or didn't start at all and it led to the whole MPI job being aborted. Muting those messages is not the right solution - you should dig deeper and find the root cause.

Comment: I don't remember all of my Open MPI errors. Does this always mean that a process didn't start? Could it also be that the application didn't call `MPI_Finalize`?

Comment: @WesleyBland, Open MPI gives a specific error if one or more processes did not call `MPI_Finalize` on exit.

Comment: @HristoIliev Well, I wish I had the knowledge and time to properly fix it, but as I said the fact is the program seems to be running without greater problem. Even if this error is an important one, I don't need to see hundreds of them cluttering my output. I know muting them does not fix the underlying problem, but it would fix the "too large and annoying output" problem. (Actually, they appear in the error stream, so it can be mitigated by redirecting stderr elsewhere.)